# Communicating over unix domain sockets between Server written in C and client written in python

Tags: python, c, networking, unix-socket

I am trying to send / receive data over unix domain socket between a server written in C and client written in Python. When i try to unpack the data received i am getting this error.

> struct.error: unpack str size does not match format

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect("/tmp/udfile")
Msg = struct.pack('I I 64s I 64s I 2048s', 1, 2, "SAMPLE1", 0, "SAMPLE2", 0, "SAMPLE3")
client.sendall(Msg)
Reply = client.recv(2192)
opcode, atype, btype, ctype, dtype, ftype, etype = struct.unpack('I I 64s I 64s I 2048s', Reply)
```

Would like to know whether this is possible in the first place. If yes, what is that i am missing.

Comment: Where did the error happen? What data was received? Have you tried debugging using `pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()`?

Comment: Thanks. I never knew about this pdb module. Used this and was able to debug the problem. there was a mismatch in size.

Answer (score 0):

The clue here is `SOCK_STREAM`.  *Stream*.  You have a *stream* connection to the other program.  Message boundaries are not guaranteed.  You got past the first hurdle - you used `sendall` instead of `send`.  You didn't get past the second one, though.  `recv(N)` is not guaranteed to return `N` bytes.  It will return *up to* `N` bytes.  Since you need exactly 2192 bytes for `struct.unpack` to succeed, you need to call `recv` in a loop and accumulate the results in a buffer until you have accumulated 2192 bytes.  Then you can call `struct.unpack`.